# Learning to ride tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is there a tag for learning to ride a bicycle?

There is [children](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children), but not all children are learners and not all learners are children.

There is [training](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training), but that doesn't really fit either.

Answer (score 1):

How about [new] or [new-rider] ?